# Advanced Python logging system

Tags: python, logging

I've been writing Python for years, but I've only just started using it in bigger programs than just simple server scripts. This means I now also want to use a more advanced logging system. To make things simple I created the following logger:

```
import logging
from inspect import getframeinfo, stack


logger = logging.getLogger()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-7s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('mm.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def l(*args, **kwargs):
    level = kwargs.get('level', 'info').lower()
    assert level in ('debug', 'info', 'warning', 'error', 'critical')
    caller = getframeinfo(stack()[1][0])
    file_line = "%s:%d - " % (caller.filename, caller.lineno)
    logger_input = file_line + ' '.join([str(a) for a in args])
    getattr(logger, level)(logger_input)
```

This logs to stdout and to a logfile and also logs the filename and the line number from which the log is made. It can be used as follows:

```
from tools import l

l('Log message')  # logs in INFO by default
l('Log message one', 'log message two')  # log multiple messages
l('Log message', level='critical')  # log in critical level
```

which creates something like this:

```
2017-10-10 20:47:16,170 root    INFO     test.py:5 - Log message
2017-10-10 20:47:16,171 root    INFO     test.py:14 - Log message one log message two
2017-10-10 20:47:16,171 root    CRITICAL test.py:116 - Log message
```

I import this in all the other files of my program and it seems to work quite ok. It enables to me to run the program from the command line and see the output, as well as running it as a daemon and seeing the output in the log files later. Furthermore, it's easy for debugging because it also logs the filename and line number, and I can easily change the default logging level with one line. Lastly, the use of a single `l` shortens the way of logging things. All in all, I'm quite happy with it.

I'm unsure if this is for some reason stupid though. Maybe there are situations which I can't oversee right now which would make this mess up things. Maybe the default conversion to strings is not smart for some reason?

Could anybody enlighten me as to what could be wrong with this or how it could be made better/more robust? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Are you sure about your example? Not `l('Log message one','log message two')`?

Comment: @Zeta - You're right. Although this also works it doesn't show the thing I was trying to show.. :-)

Answer (score 7):

### [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) Conventions

- Top-level functions should be separated (preceded and followed) by two blank lines:

  ```
  logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


  def l(*args, **kwargs):
       <body>
  ```
- Don't mix single quotes `'` and double quotes `"` in a single file (or project). You may you use either of them, but

  > Pick a rule and stick to it.
- Lines should not exceed 79 characters (or 73 characters for documentation).

### General concerns

- `l` is a bad name for a function. Always try to pick a name that describes what the function does, like `log`.
- You haven't added any [docstrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstring) to your function. If anyone else wants to use your code, they have no way to know what parameters to pass (or what the function actually does). According to [PEP-257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/),

  > All modules should normally have docstrings, and all functions and classes exported by a module should also have docstrings.

  A good docstring describes what your function does, what parameters it expects, what it returns and if applicable, what `Exception` it raises if something goes wrong.
- `assert` should really only be used for debugging purposes, not in the 'stable' release. I propose raising a `ValueError` instead.
- Since you're only retrieving the `level` argument from `**kwargs`, you may as well make it a keyword argument.

### Improved code

Taking into account all of the above, here's my rewritten version of your code:

```
import logging
from inspect import getframeinfo, stack

logger = logging.getLogger()
formatter = logging.Formatter('
    %(asctime)s %(name)-7s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s
')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('mm.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def log(*args, level='info'):
    """Log a message to stdout and a log file.
    Arguments:
    - *args: All messages to be logged (as strings).

    - level: The level for debugging. Any of 'debug', 'info', 'warning',
             'error', 'critical'. Defaults to 'info'.

    Raises:
    - ValueError if an invalid `level` argument is passed.
    """
    LEVELS = ('debug', 'info', 'warning', 'error', 'critical')
    level = level.lower()
    if level not in LEVELS:
        raise ValueError('`level` argument must be any of {}'.format(
            str(LEVELS)[1:-1]
        )
    caller = getframeinfo(stack()[1][0])
    file_line = '%s:%d - ' % (caller.filename, caller.lineno)
    logger_input = file_line + ' '.join([str(a) for a in args])
    getattr(logger, level)(logger_input)
```

*The use of `*args` in the above snippet breaks backward compatibility!*

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The things you mention are all valid points. But I guess it means that once I use your adjusted version, the general working of the logging code is pretty good? I mean, this wouldn't create problems when using concurrency?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't put a keyword argument after the `*args` argument. That is why I used the `**kwargs` for it.

Comment: @kramer65 You can in Python 3.x. (And you did not specify which Python version you are using, as far as I can see). However it might make sense to at least mention that this breaks backwards compatibility.

Comment: @kramer65 I'm not confident I'm qualified to answer your questions regarding concurrency, as I don't have a lot of experience with it. Perhaps you can open an updated question (or edit this one) to specifically express your concerns on that part.